# Python executable cannot read file

Tags: python, python-2.7, file-io, py2exe, linecache

Given below is the code that I am using to read values form a file

```
import linecache
line_number=line_number+1
linecache.getline("write.txt", line_number)
```

I am using **py2exe** to convert the file into an executable. The problem is after conversion to **exe** it cannot read the file.

The error message is: 
**Could not convert string to a float**

As suggested in the comment the full error trace is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "logic.py", line 437, in <module>
  File "logic.py", line 224, in readdata
ValueError: could not convert string to float:
```

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Can you post all error trace message ?

Comment: @fred.yu Edited the question as you said. Please check and see.

Comment: Open line 224 in `logic.py`, and see what makes the error.

Comment: @fred.yu I checked that already. Its the line where I try to access the value that I am reading from the file.

Comment: I tried this code snippet, but it runs OK after I convert it to `exe`. So you try to comment some unrelated code and narrow down the problem.

Comment: @fred.yu Did you try to access the value that you are getting from the file?

Comment: I try to get the content of the file `write.txt`, but failed. So I think it's a problem when use `linecache` with `py2exe`. Please look at [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/wxpython-users/rOpIQEuX-NE).